# How do I export and restore my iptables settings?

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat

I have what appears to be weird and convoluted set of rules which work for me at the moment. Is there a way of "exporting" those and saving them to a file so that they can be restored later on in case things are messed up?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With suitable privilege

```
iptables-save > /some/file
```

will save your iptables configuration to /some/file

and

```
iptables-restore < /some/file
```

will restore your saved configuration from `/some/file`.

Comment: Ah... I didnt know of those. I kept looking for some command line options!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. It writes your rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables; if you (re)start iptables after you do this, your rules should be there :)

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` commands ?

Comment: This tone is a bit rude my friend :)